# Google Website Translator suddenly displaying "Original text" on bottom of screen

Tags: html, google-translate

Our website uses the Google Website Translator plugin (https://translate.google.com/manager/website/)

Yesterday it suddenly started to display a large "Original text" box at the bottom of every page, and the translator toolbar at the top of the page is sized in a weird rectangle instead of spanning across the top of the page.

We noticed a few other sites having this issue but I haven't seen any information from Google or others reporting this issue.

Is there a solution for this problem?

Example from comments: http://www.visitestespark.com/

Scroll down to the bottom of the page to see the error.  Thanks Nucleon!

Comment: Screenshot or site where we can replicate the problem for study?

Comment: http://www.visitestespark.com/ is one example of this. Translate it at the bottom, and you'll see it go haywire. Just noticed today.

Comment: it's a google issue, here is another one http://www.nfsa.gov.au/

Comment: For now, instead of removing the feature completely we simply set the visibility to hidden: #goog-gt-tt { visibility: hidden;}

Comment: https://twitter.com/Dan_Treasure/status/411276915824013312

Comment: and another one: https://support.google.com/translate/?hl=en-AU

Comment: All of my websites that use it are all exhibiting the same behavior.

Comment: google just removed translate from it's own site -> https://support.google.com/translate/. but it was there -> http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:t_9WkD2F-LoJ:https://support.google.com/translate/+&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=au&client=firefox-a

Comment: but they forgot to remove it from -> http://googletranslate.blogspot.com.au/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem appears to be fixed by Google as of Dec. 13, 2013.  The Google Translate functionality appears to be identical to how it was on Dec. 10, 2013.